# embed Power Bi dashboards view into CRM

Tags: sharepoint, dynamics-crm-2015, powerbi

Does any one have an idea of how could i embed the power bi dashboards view without the data in dynamics CRM online,I'm trying using SharePoint online but it's not working.

please give me your advice.

Answer (score 1):

Right now Power BI dashboards are not embeddable.  Embedding dashboards is on our roadmap.  You can follow the following idea to keep updated when we add this capability: https://ideas.powerbi.com/forums/268152-developer-apis/suggestions/8528704-allow-powerbi-dashboards-to-be-embedded-via-iframe